# How to share a file between two repositories using Git & Bitbucket?

Tags: css, git, bitbucket

I'm building a web-application that has 2 separate components: The front-end that runs in the user's browser (Javascript + Angular) and a back-end REST Api (Python/Django) that runs on my server and feeds data to all the front-ends. The two parts of this app are placed into two separate Git repositories and stored in BitBucket.

The front-end displays the data to the user win a beautiful interface that has lots of nice CSS defined. The back-end sends emails to the users.

I would like the look-and-feel of the emails to exactly match the front-end's display. All the user's interaction should have a uniform presentation. So where/how should I put the CSS such that it is available in both repositories, but I only have to make changes to it in one place??

How do I do this with the tools I'm using: Git & Bitbucket?

Answer (score 8):

**I think the CSS should be in a separate "third" project altogether.**

Especially since you may even want to reuse the nice CSS for another project, or break the existing projects into more repositories.

So the strategy is:

1. Create a third repository, e.g. project_css
2. In both current projects, add references to that repository using `git subtree` or `git submodule`.

For example, if you prefer `git subtree` to have the third project's files part of each of the two existing projects, you can follow a blog/tutorial like this one:

https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/

Whether you use `git subtree` or `git submodule`, that depends on the trade-offs you're ok with.

Answer (score 1):

write a script in the git pre-commit hook, if the css file is changed, then the script could push the change to BitBucket.  See

```
git help githooks
```

Comment: To which repository should it be pushed? How do I use the same file in two different repositories?

Answer (score 1):

**You may merge the two repositories into one, by adding a second remote repository.**

It's easier to maintain.

Pick one of your repositories, let's call it `repo1`. The first step is to add in `repo1` a second remote repository, called `repo2`. That's your second project. Then fetch the branches of `repo2` into your `repo1`. All branches will sit "happily" together in one repository.

The next step is to merge the mainlines of the two projects into one branch. This will work flawless if the folders and files don't "clash" with each other. You may need to rename certain folders before doing that.

Now both projects are sitting together and can share the CCS files. 
Afterwards you may disregard `repo2`.

The whole operation is done in your local repository. When finished you push everything to a central server such as BitBucket.

The concept is that a git repository is just a "house" for branches. And it's fine if those branches don't share a common ancestor. We have used this method to reduce the number of repositories of projects which work very closely together.